# How to create dynamic *ngFor in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I would like to create a table component. The table component needs data which is processed by *ngFor to display the rows of data. But the problem I am facing is how to send dynamic *ngFor query via input.

The reason for this is I am using the pagination filter for one table which is not used by some tables.

So when building table with pagination, ngFor would be

```
*ngFor="let report of reports | paginate: config"
```

without pagination *ngFor would be

`*ngFor="let report of reports"`

Any help is appreciated. I believe it could be done via *ngIf , but I believe this could be done in a more effective way?

Comment: Cannot you just use *ngFor="let report of reports | paginate: config" and in case of no pagination make the page size same to whole data ?